# Display data from JSON external API and display to DIALOGFLOW using AXIOS

Tags: node.js, axios, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I need help with **Displaying the response** I get from my API **to Dialogflow UI.** Here is my code. I am currently using WebHook to connect Dialogflow to backend in Heroku.
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGw0P.png)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("../../reactpageagent-dxug-firebase-adminsdk-26f6q-e1563ff30f.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://reactpageagent-dxug.firebaseio.com"
});

const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = (request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add('Welcome to my agent');
  }

  function rhymingWordHandler(agent) {
    const word = agent.parameters.word;
    agent.add(`Here are the rhyming words for ${word}`)
    axios.get(`https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=${word}`)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
        result.data.map(wordObj => {
          console.log(wordObj.word);
          agent.add(JSON.stringify(wordObj.word));
          return;
          // agent.end(`${wordObj.word}`);
        });
      });
  };

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('rhymingWord', rhymingWordHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
}
```

When I console.log my the result. **I get the data from the API in my console.log output**, but the **Data is not displayed in Dialogflow UI** I also do not get any error.

[Heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOmVS.png)

Comment: I tried running your [API](https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=hello). It is giving a collection of words. Do you want to show all the words? I think agent.add wouldn't work inside map method. You'll have to either choose the first word or create a string of words.

Comment: A string of words will be Fine, How do I achieve that Sir, Perhaps a sample code would be appreciated

Comment: Try adding return before axios.get call.

Answer (score 1):

I had real trouble with the `result.data.map` line of code.
In the end, I avoided it and instead processed `result.data` after the `.then((result) => {` line by checking the array length that my API returned, and if it was `> 0`, loop through it to output each line individually, using `agent.add`. If the array length was 0, I used `agent.add` to display a message saying 'No records found'. I used a `catch` to log any errors (again, using `agent.add` to send an error message to the user).